# Inverse Laplace transform of $ \bar{U}(r,s) = \frac{1}{s} \frac{K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, r \right)}{K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, b \right)}$

Tags: laplace-transform, bessel-functions, inverse-laplace

What is the inverse Laplace transform of
$$
\bar{U}(r,s) = \frac{1}{s} \frac{K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, r \right)}{K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, b \right)}   \tag{12}.
$$
?

**Related** (but not providing the answer):

1. [Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{π\cosh(\sqrt s)}{2 s^{3/2} \sinh(\sqrt s)}$ using complex integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224588/inverse-laplace-transform-of-frac%cf%80-cosh-sqrt-s2-s3-2-sinh-sqrt-s)
2. [Inverse Laplace of $\frac{\sinh{x\sqrt{s}}}{s^2\sinh{\sqrt{s}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965257/inverse-laplace-of-frac-sinhx-sqrtss2-sinh-sqrts)
3. [Inverse Laplace transform of $K_0 \left(r \sqrt{s^2-1}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862697/inverse-laplace-transform-of-k-0-leftr-sqrts2-1-right)
4. [Inverse Laplace Transform of the modified Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845034/inverse-laplace-transform-of-the-modified-bessel-function)
5. [How do we use contour integration to invert a Laplace transform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588538/how-do-we-use-contour-integration-to-invert-a-laplace-transform)
6. [Find the Green's Function and solution of a heat equation on the half line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350742/find-the-greens-function-and-solution-of-a-heat-equation-on-the-half-line)
7. [Solution of the transient heat equation for an infinite domain with a circular hole and angular symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850114/solution-of-the-transient-heat-equation-for-an-infinite-domain-with-a-circular-h)
8. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

Comment: Note that you can assume that $\alpha=r=1$.

Comment: The solution to this particular inverse Laplace transform for the same problem is found in "Conduction of Heat in Solids" by H.S. Carslaw and J.C. Jaeger (Second Edition) - Clarendon Press. Ch. XIII p. 335. The inverse Laplace transform has a branch point at the origin and the integral is evaluated on each side of the branch cut on the negative axis. The final result is provided as an integral of a combination of standard Bessel functions $J_{0}$ and $Y_{0}$.

Comment: Also, in this book, the specifics of the contour integration are discussed, without proof, in the section "Inversion Theorem for the Laplace Transformation" on p. 302, 303, as well as in Appendix $I$ p.479.

Comment: @Jean-LucBoulnois - If you post that as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: @Gary - Yes, I had just found it. If I am not wrong, it contains essentially the same information as the reference by Jean-Luc Boulnois.
Did you check your solution is the same as in Carslaw & Jaeger, including signs, factors?